# Go Lang RESTful API not working JSON

Tags: json, rest, go

I'm trying to make a RESTful API on Go Lang returning JSON value. I am not getting any value on the page when I load it. Could anyone help me out here.. ?

```
type sessiond struct{
   apiKey string `json:"apiKey"`
   token string `json:"token"`
}

func dummy(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   se:=sessiond{apiKey:key,token:"erer"}
   log.Println(se);    // Iam getting the value here ! but nothing on the page.
   w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
   w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
      if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(se); err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   //res.R200(w, se)
}
```

Comment: What is "res" in your code? I could not find corresponding variable.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I should have removed it. 'res' is basically another module that contains the json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(se) call.

Comment: Also: good Go style is to call it APIKey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Export](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) the fields in type `sessiond` by starting the field name with an uppercase letter.

```
type sessiond struct{
   ApiKey string `json:"apiKey"`
   Token string `json:"token"`
}
```

The JSON encoder and decoder ignore unexported fields.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much.

Comment: For newbies like me: http://www.goinggo.net/2014/03/exportedunexported-identifiers-in-go.html